Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met
i m getting error on CopyToAsync when filelist is having more than 1 file in case of 1 file it is working fine. issue could be related to concurrency i am not sure about that solution will be really appreciated
        CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_configuration["AzureBlobStorage"]);
        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("interestgroupattachment");
        var blockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

        using (var stream = await blockBlob.OpenWriteAsync())
        using (var zip = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            var files = fileNames;
            foreach (var docfile in fileList)
            {
                using (var fstream = docfile)
                {
                    var entry = zip.CreateEntry(fileNames[counter], CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                    using (var innerFile = entry.Open())
                    {
                        await fstream.CopyToAsync(innerFile);
                    }
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }



I'm getting error on CopyToAsync when filelist is having more than 1 file in case of 1 file it is working fine. issue could be related to concurrency i am not sure about that solution will be really appreciated.

When CopyToAsync method to copy multiple files to a zip archive, but it is not working when there is more than one file. This issue may be caused by concurrency problems.
You can use the below code to upload multiple files to Azure Blob Storage as a single zip archive.
Code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace AzureBlobStorageExample
{
    class Program
    {
        private static IConfiguration _configuration;

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            _configuration = builder.Build();

            List<Stream> fileList = new List<Stream>
            {
                new FileStream("file1.txt", FileMode.Open),
                new FileStream("file2.txt", FileMode.Open)
            };
            List<string> fileNames = new List<string> { "file1.txt", "file2.txt" };

            string filename = "output.zip";

            await UploadFilesToBlobAsync(fileList, fileNames, filename);

            foreach (var file in fileList)
            {
                file.Dispose();
            }
        }

        static async Task UploadFilesToBlobAsync(List<Stream> fileList, List<string> fileNames, string filename)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_configuration["AzureBlobStorage"]);
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("test");
            var blockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

            using (var stream = await blockBlob.OpenWriteAsync())
            using (var zip = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
            {
                int counter = 0; 

                foreach (var docfile in fileList)
                {
                    using (var fstream = docfile)
                    {
                        var entry = zip.CreateEntry(fileNames[counter], CompressionLevel.Optimal);

                        using (var innerFile = entry.Open())
                        {
                            await fstream.CopyToAsync(innerFile);
                        }
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The above code reads the configuration from an appsettings.json file, creates a list of files to upload, and calls the UploadFilesToBlobAsync method to upload the files to Azure Blob Storage.
The above method loops through the list of files and creates a new entry in the zip archive for each file. It opens the file stream asynchronously and copies the contents of the file to the entry stream using the CopyToAsync method. Finally, it increments the counter to ensure that the correct file name is used for each entry.
Portal:

